# JPA Entities consistency - how to deal with it?

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, entity, consistency

Lets assume I have entities: User, Group and Notification.

```
//User has field List<Group> groups and List<Notification> myNotifications.
public class User {
    private List<Group> groups;
    private List<Notification> myNotifications;
}

//Group has field List<Notification> notifications.
public class Group {
    private List<Notification> notifications;
}
```

And now, when user create his account, I save User entity into the database with empty list of groups. 
Then, when user create or will be added to a group he wants to add some notification to it.

When I create and then save notification I want it to be saved to some Group notifications list and to some User (creator of notification) notifications list. 
I dont want situation where my notification is saved to either one or another list. I need to be sure notification will be saved both: to User notifiactions list entity and to Group notifications list.

What should I do to avoid inconsistency?

For now, my services' methods are annotated @Transactional (spring transaction) as it is said to provide consistency. But I wonder if this is enough?

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is enough. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Comment: I have read that article :) thanks @JBNizet